# Верстка блока с трансформацией

Tags: css, вёрстка

Как сверстать такой блок как на изображении? Но по умолчанию картинка правильной прямоугольной формы. Задача заключается именно сверстать такую форму с background-image.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)?

Comment: Вынести фон в псевдоэлемент и применить transform: skew?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parallelogram {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 8%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/3OaUddf.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
}

.parallelogram2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 8%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FC0FC0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallelogram">
  <div class="parallelogram2"></div>
</div>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать. Либо можно в редакторе наложить соответствующий цветовой эффект и использовать эту фотографию с эффектом в качестве `background-image`, т.е. без создания и наложения второго блока с цветом и прозрачностью.

Comment: В сниппете можно (и нужно) не указывать теги относящиеся к формированию страницы (html, head, body), желательно минимизировать содержимое, чтобы автору и другим было понятнее, что можно взять из этого кода и для чего оно нужно (тут больше речь о комментариях к коду). Так же, чтобы урл картинок не слетел, лучше их хранить на [Imgir](https://imgur.com/), для этого даже регистрироваться не обязательно :)

Comment: @De.Minov, картинки надо прям тут загружать, а не на imgur.

Comment: @Qwertiy, они всё равно грузятся на Imgur)

Comment: @De.Minov, нет, там поддомен отдельный. И другие правила хранения, кажется.